# Чтение музыки: числа в вызовах GetString

Tags: c#

Всем привет, вот я искал инфу о том, как прочитать Артиста, Альбом, и пр. Так вот на форму Microsoft нашёл этот код

```
byte[]b = new byte[128];
string sTitle;
string sSinger;
string sAlbum;
string sYear;
string sComm;

FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:\Kalimba.mp3 ", FileMode.Open);
fs.Seek(-128, SeekOrigin.End);
fs.Read(b, 0, 128);
bool isSet = false;
String sFlag = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 0, 3);
if (sFlag.CompareTo("TAG") == 0) {
    System.Console.WriteLine("Tag   is   setted! ");
    isSet = true;
}

if (isSet) {
    //get   title   of   song; 
    sTitle = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 3, 30);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Title: " + sTitle);
    //get   singer; 
    sSinger = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 33, 30);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Singer: " + sSinger);
    //get   album; 
    sAlbum = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 63, 30);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Album: " + sAlbum);
    //get   Year   of   publish; 
    sYear = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 93, 4);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Year: " + sYear);
    //get   Comment; 
    sComm = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 97, 30);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Comment: " + sComm);
}
System.Console.WriteLine("Any   key   to   exit! ");
System.Console.Read();
```

Но я вот не понял конкретно эти строки

```
sTitle = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 3, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Title: " + sTitle);
sSinger = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 33, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Singer: " + sSinger);
sAlbum = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 63, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Album: " + sAlbum);
sYear = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 93, 4);
System.Console.WriteLine("Year: " + sYear);
sComm = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(b, 97, 30);
System.Console.WriteLine("Comment: " + sComm);
```

Откуда берутся числа 33, 30, 63, 30, 93, 4, 97, 30? Или надо знать просто, где расположены эти данные в музыке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что ответ на этот вопрос находится в спецификации формата mp3.

Comment: Скорее в "спецификации" ID3v1.